# Generic type attribute with OR constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is it possible to have a type independent attribute class, possibly decorated with an 'where or' constraint?

Example:

```
public class Attribute<T> where T: string || bool {

   public const char ATTRIBUTE_CHAR = 'a';

   public string Key    { get; set; }
   public T      Value  { get; set; }

   public Attribute(string key, T value) {
       Key   = key;
       Value = value;
   }

   public Attribute(string key, bool value = true)
   : base(key, value) {}

   public Attribute(string key, string value)
   : base(key, value) {}

   public override string ToString() {

        if(typeof(value) == bool && (bool)value)
             return String.Format({0}={1},
                 ATTRIBUTE_CHAR, key);
        else return String.Format({0}={1}:{2},
            ATTRIBUTE_CHAR, key, (string)value);
   }

}
```

So that this:

```
Attribute<bool> BoolAttr1     = new Attribute<bool>("bool_1");
Attribute<bool> BoolAttr2     = new Attribute<bool>("bool_2", false);
Attribute<string> StringAttr1 = new Attribute<string>("string_1", "val1");
Attribute<string> StringAttr2 = new Attribute<string>("string_2", "val2");

...everything.ToString();
```

Would produce the following output

```
a=bool_1
a=string_1:val1
a=string_2:val2
```

But that something like this is never possible:

```
Attribute<int>...
```

Comment: can you clarify the purpose of attribute class?

Comment: @daryal To parse & provide something like this in a library:                                                 `a=recvonly CRLF a=rtpmap:99 h263-1998/90000` Here you got 2 types of attribute, one is boolean (only a key which 'enables' the attribute, if it would be false it wouldn't appear in a message) and one is string (a key 'rtpmap' and a value '99 h263...)

Comment: And why do you need generics? You have no common logic whatsoever in your `Attribute<T>` class. The whhole point of generics is to treat the same way objects of different type. If you need lines such as `if (typeof(T) == bool)` then its a signal, that you are doing it wrong. And to answer your question - no, there is no `or`.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak Uff, thanks for clearing me up. Would you please mind to post your comment as an answer so I can upboat / accept?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting T to string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455050/restricting-t-to-string-and-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `or`. What you probably want to do is this:

```
interface IKeyValue<TKey, TValue>
{
   public TKey Key {get;set;}
   public TValue Value {get;set;}
}

public class Attribute : IKeyValue<string, string>
{
   public override string ToString() 
   {
        return String.Format("{0}={1}:{2}", Constants.ATTRIBUTE_CHAR, Key, Value);
   }
}

public class BoolAttribute : IKeyValue<string, bool>
{
   public override string ToString() 
   {
        return Value ? String.Format("{0}={1}", Constants.ATTRIBUTE_CHAR, Key) : String.Empty;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract attribute and your required implementations.
Each Attribute can then be handled in the required way. (Casting to Attribute), but no Attribute of an unsupported type could be created.

```
public abstract class Attribute<T>
{
    public abstract T getValue();
}

public class StringAttribute : Attribute<String>
{
    String value;

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}

public class BooleanAttribute : Attribute<Boolean>
{
    Boolean value;

    public Boolean getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Also this allows you to implement type-dependant attribute functions very easy. (like toString() etc.)